# Поиск подпоследовательности в последовательности

Tags: c

Определите, сколько раз во входной последовательности встречается подпоследовательность 1, 2, 3, . . . , 10.

Помогите пожалуйста, ни одной мысли по решению.

Имеющийся код:

```
/*Определите, сколько раз во входной последовательности встре-
чается подпоследовательность 1, 2, 3, . . . , 10..*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

#define NUM_MEMB    32

int main()
{
    int *arrX = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_MEMB);
    printf("arrX:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MEMB; i++)
    {
        //arrX[i] = (rand()- RAND_MAX/2)%10 + i;
        arrX[i] = rand()%10;
        //printf(" %i ",arrX[i]);
    }
    arrX[5] = 1;
    arrX[6] = 2;
    arrX[7] = 3;
    arrX[8] = 4;
    arrX[9] = 5;
    arrX[10] = 6;
    arrX[11] = 7;
    arrX[12] = 8;
    arrX[13] = 9;
    arrX[14] = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_MEMB; i++)
        printf(" %i ",arrX[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неточно указано. Например, в последовательности 1 2 3 7 4 8 5 6 7 8 9 10 — нужная подпоследовательность есть или нет?

Comment: Если нужна именно "цельная" подпоследовательность — можно применить любой метод поиска подстрок в строке. Например, просто идти по строке и, встретив 1, проверять — это искомая подстрока или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть `a` последовательность длины `n`, `b` - последовательность длины `m`. Будем искать сколько раз последовательность `b` может быть подпоследовательностью последовательность `a`. Для удобства индексируем последовательности с единицы.

Введём функцию `c(i, j)` которая берёт из `a` первые `i` элементов, из `b` - первые `j` элементов и решает задачу для этих частичных последовательностей.

Число которое нас интересует - `c(n, m)`.

Как можно вычислить `c(i, j)`?

Если `a[i] = b[j]`, то подпоследовательность или заканчивается в `a[i]` или заканчивается раньше. Первых `c(i - 1, j - 1)` штук, вторых - `c(i - 1, j)` штук.

Если `a[i] != b[j]`, то любая подпоследовательность заканчивается раньше. Таких `c(i - 1, j)` штук.

Заметим что `c(i, 0) = 1` - в любой последовательности одна пустая подпоследовательность. И `c(0, j > 0) = 0`.

Имея набор `c(i, *)` можно вычислить `c(i + 1, *)`.

Comment: Судя по тому, как ТС создает массив, у вас решение слишком серьезное, и нужно просто искать 10 последовательных чисел.

Comment: @Mikhailo, что-то есть в ваших словах.